# Android: Is there a way to simulating D-Pad Events (API 10)?

Tags: android, simulation, keyevent, d-pad

The problem is very simple. I have to simulate the dpad events (UP,DOWN,RIGHT,LEFT,CENTER) for navigate in my GUI that consists of a lot of buttons and other elements. With the simulator D-Pad I can without a line code navigate throw this GUI. But how can I do this programmatically?

I have tried a lot with no success:

- `KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT);
         View.dispatchKeyEvent(event);`
  Nothing happens (the focus should move one element to right)
- I have also read a lot about windowManager.injectKeyEvent but found nothing that works.
- And also Instrumentation can help for simulating keyevents but more for testing, not for use in the application itself.

I think there is a solution, because talkback can simulate the physical D-Pad (http://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/source/browse/trunk/ime/latinime/src/com/googlecode/eyesfree/inputmethod/latin/LatinIME.java)

Comment: I have found the talkback solution, they works with InputConnection. 
final InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
But i have to send the D-Pad keyevents from an activity.

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
```

You can move the cursor in an `EditText` by simulating DPAD down/up events. The up event would probably be enough, but I am simulating the full event to be safe.

### Left

```
ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT));
ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT));
```

### Right

```
ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT));
ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT));
```

### Up

```
ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP));
ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP));
```

### Down

```
ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN));
ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN));
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the smart solution (e.g for go down):

```
bic=new BaseInputConnection(this.getWindow().getDecorView(),false);
KeyEvent event2 = new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN,0, KeyEvent.META_SYM_ON, 0, 0, KeyEvent.FLAG_VIRTUAL_HARD_KEY); 

bic.sendKeyEvent(event2);
```

That's all, an internal algorithm to find the next element in your selected direction

Comment: That doesn't work for me. sendKeyEvent always returns false which indicates the "BaseInputConnection is no longer valid". Whatever that is suppose to mean.

Answer (score 2):

You have two way to achieve your goal:

First,

```
Instrumentation inst=new Instrumentation();
inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(int  keycode);
```

Prerequisites:In the same process.

Second,for examble,wo want to simulate KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP

```
getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP));
```

Prerequisites:Must bind inputmethd

Answer (score 1):

Try using KeyEvent.ACTION_UP instead of ACTION_DOWN. Solved similar issue for me.