# What APIs can be used to control the Glass OS UI?

Tags: google-glass

Does anyone know if it is possible for developers to control the Glass OS UI either remotely or via a glass app? So, for example, being able to generate a SWIPE_LEFT event that causes the top level OS UI to move left.

MyGlass has remote control functionality that does this, but I can't see any obvious APIs that they'd be using. I am assuming they have some private APIs.

Comment: Not sure on specifics, but I'm pretty sure Glass converts dpad events to the appropriate swipe events. This question might be down the right path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568343/android-is-there-a-way-to-simulating-d-pad-events-api-10

Comment: Thanks Zach. From what I can see all of these methods are locked down to the calling application scope. Windows, Instrumentation, etc. I think the fact that TeamViewer (remote UI control) only appears to work with special Samsung permissions suggests it's not possible without access to private APIs.